# When should I validate the presence of an ActiveRecord association object vs its id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Suppose I have an ActiveRecord association like:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
end
```

A city without a state should be invalid. It seems that both of these are possible validations:

```
validates :state,    presence: true
# OR
validates :state_id, presence: true
```

I would guess that they are identical, since:

- `belongs_to` creates methods `state` and `state=`
- `state=` sets the `state_id`

However, I've just fixed a failing spec by changing it to check for the id instead of the object.

Are these two ways of validating both acceptable? If so, when would you use one or the other?

Comment: Can we see your original and fixed spec?

Answer (score 17):

`validates :state` will use the relationship from city to state (the belongs_to) along with the foreign key whereas `validates :state_id` alone will just use the column state_id and see if it has any value at all.

My preferred method is to validate `state` (the relationship) as this requires both the key and the relationship to be present.

Validating state_id will work, in that it will make sure that a state id exists, however it won't check for the validity of the code, i.e. that a state actually 'exists' for any given state key in City.

Basically if the foreign keys (for state_id) used in City all exist as actual records in State, the effect is the same.  The difference would show if you had an invalid state code in state.

Answer (score 1):

What if you did something like

```
s = State.new
c = City.new
c.state = s
c.valid?
```

I haven't tried this but I'm guessing that, if you're checking for the presence of c.state_id, it will be missing, even though c does have a state (because the ID hasn't been generated yet, because the state hasn't been saved yet).

That is to say, if what you care about is the presence of the state, you should validate the presence of the state.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to allow the model to be more robust and accept either or.  So in your particular situation, City could accept either a `State` object or a `state_id`, but is required to send one of them.

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :state, :state_id

  validates :state,    presence: true, if: proc{|c| c.state_id.blank? }
  validates :state_id, presence: true, if: proc{|c| c.state.blank?    }

  belongs_to :state
end
```

**Edit:** Removed the double negative in the validate statement.  Originally had `unless: proc{|c| !c.state_id.blank? }`

Comment: I like your approach. Nitpick: there's no need for `unless !blank?`; either `if blank?` or `unless present?` would work.

Comment: That is very true, i was going to put `present?` as that is simply the inverse of `!blank?`, but I prefer the readability of `!blank`.  But doing `if blank?` works as well without the double negative :P

Answer (score -1):

According to [Rails 4 Way by Obie Fernandez](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321944275):

> When you're trying to ensure that an association is present, pass its
>   foreign key attribute, not the association variable itself

```
validates :region_id, :presence => true
validate :region_exists

def region_exists
  errors.add(:region_id, "does not exist") unless Region.exists?(region_id)
end
```

The book does not explain why you should use this as opposed to

```
validates :region, :presence => true
```

But I know that these guys know their stuff.

Comment: This is kind of the same as `validate :region, presence: true` except that it also enforces a check that the association exists through the database. It seems a little weird to do it this way, because it offers you no validation of the in memory object. In experience, it's easier to just validate the object and add a foreign key constraint to ensure that the keys are always valid.

Comment: Like I said, these guys know their stuff :). Good point though.

Comment: Maybe its because of performance reasons, because validates :region loads region from DB every time an object is validated, while validates :region_id won't do it.